# javafx run one after the other

Tags: java, button, javafx, javafx-8

I have a problem with my code. 
With one buttonclick I would like to determine an IP address and from this IP the two-successive IP addresses but I also want to check if the IP addresses are reachable. The check takes a few seconds. I want the IP addresses to be displayed and the check should be done in the background.
How can I do that?

```
   public void GetIP() {
        String mn = tfmn.getText();
        String d = "cachea." + mn + ".de.kaufland";

        try {
            InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(d);
            int intIP = ByteBuffer.wrap(i.getAddress()).getInt();

            intIP += 1496;

            i = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
            String ip = i.getHostAddress();

            tfip1.setText(ip);

            //Check IP
            boolean reachable = i.isReachable(1000);
            if (reachable) {
                tfipinfo1.setText("IP-Addresse reachable");
                tfipinfo1.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;");
            } else {
                tfipinfo1.setText("IP-Adresse ist not reachable");
                tfipinfo1.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
            }

            // next IP
            intIP += 1;

            InetAddress i2 = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
            ip = i2.getHostAddress();
            tfip2.setText(ip);

            //Check IP-Address
            boolean reachable2 = i2.isReachable(1000);
            if (reachable2) {
                tfipinfo2.setText("IP-Adresse ist erreichbar");
                tfipinfo2.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;");
            } else {
                tfipinfo2.setText("IP-Adresse ist nicht erreichbar");
                tfipinfo2.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
            }

            //next IP
            intIP += 1;

            InetAddress i3 = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
            ip = i3.getHostAddress();
            tfip3.setText(ip);

            //check IP
            boolean reachable3 = i3.isReachable(1000);
            if (reachable3) {
                tfipinfo3.setText("IP-Adresse ist erreichbar");
                tfipinfo3.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;");
            } else {
                tfipinfo3.setText("IP-Adresse ist nicht erreichbar");
                tfipinfo3.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
            }

          } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Der Markt existiert nicht!");

            alert.showAndWait();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0):

you make :

```
ip = i2.getHostAddress();
tfip2.setText(ip);

//Check IP-Address
boolean reachable2 = i2.isReachable(1000);
```

so the order is

- get address
- display address
- check address

you just need to make :

```
...
tfip1.setText(ip);

// next IP
intIP += 1;

InetAddress i2 = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
ip = i2.getHostAddress();
tfip2.setText(ip);
//Check IP
boolean reachable = i.isReachable(1000);
if (reachable) {
  tfipinfo1.setText("IP-Addresse reachable");
  tfipinfo1.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;");
} else {
  tfipinfo1.setText("IP-Adresse ist not reachable");
  tfipinfo1.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
}

//Check IP-Address
boolean reachable2 = i2.isReachable(1000);
if (reachable2) {
  tfipinfo2.setText("IP-Adresse ist erreichbar");
  tfipinfo2.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;");
} else {
  tfipinfo2.setText("IP-Adresse ist nicht erreichbar");
  tfipinfo2.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
}
...
```

> you can also make you IP-Address checker in another Thread

you will have something like :

```
class IPChecker extends Task {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        //your ip checker algo
        return null;
    }
}
```

and to call it :

```
...
tfip1.setText(ip);
new Thread(new IPChecker()).start();
...
```

so your will seams like that :

```
public void GetIP() {
    String mn = tfmn.getText();
    String d = "cachea." + mn + ".de.kaufland";

    try {
        InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(d);
        int intIP = ByteBuffer.wrap(i.getAddress()).getInt();

        intIP += 1496;

        i = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
        String ip = i.getHostAddress();

        tfip1.setText(ip);

        //Check IP
        new Thread(new IPChecker1()).start();

        // next IP
        intIP += 1;

        InetAddress i2 = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
        ip = i2.getHostAddress();
        tfip2.setText(ip);

        //Check IP-Address
        new Thread(new IPChecker2()).start();

        //next IP
        intIP += 1;

        InetAddress i3 = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
        ip = i3.getHostAddress();
        tfip3.setText(ip);

        //check IP
        new Thread(new IPChecker3()).start();

      } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
```

you can also define another constructor to write `new IPChecker(ip1)` and so on

Comment: Changing the order did not work and I do not know how to do that with threads. can you give me an example?

Comment: @MarkusS here is it

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you wanted to say was

> UI needs to function while the program checks the IP addresses in the background

this will make the program not hold during its time of checking the IP addresses. This can and should be achieved through separate threads as it is not recommended to use the main JavaFX thread to perform tasks other than handling the UI.

Classes required to achieve concurrency in JavaFX applications are provided in the `javafx.concurrent` package. The class that will be used in this solution is `Task`. Given below is the solution for your code segment.

```
public class IPChecker extends Task<Void>{
    private final InetAddress i;
    private TextField tf;

    public IPChecker(InetAddress i,TextField tf) {
        this.i = i;
        this.tf=tf;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception{
        boolean reachable = i.isReachable(1000);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (reachable) {
                tf.setText("IP-Addresse reachable");
                tf.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;");
            } else {
                tf.setText("IP-Adresse ist not reachable");
                tf.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}

public void GetIP() {
    String mn = tfmn.getText();
    String d = "cachea." + mn + ".de.kaufland";

    try {
        InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(d);
        int intIP = ByteBuffer.wrap(i.getAddress()).getInt();

        intIP += 1496;

        i = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
        String ip = i.getHostAddress();

        tfip1.setText(ip);

        //Check IP
        Thread t1=new Thread(new IPChecker(i,tfipinfo1));
        t1.start();

        // next IP
        intIP += 1;

        InetAddress i2 = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
        ip = i2.getHostAddress();
        tfip2.setText(ip);

        //Check IP-Address
        Thread t2=new Thread(new IPChecker(i2,tfipinfo2));
        t2.start();

        //next IP
        intIP += 1;

        InetAddress i3 = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intIP));
        ip = i3.getHostAddress();
        tfip3.setText(ip);

        //check IP
        Thread t3=new Thread(new IPChecker(i3,tfipinfo3));
        t3.start();

    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Der Markt existiert nicht!");

        alert.showAndWait();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've created a class named `IPChecker` to perform the actions that requires to be run in the background. This class requires you to pass the `InetAddress` object and the `TextField` objects that the work is to be performed on.

> Why is that `Platform.runLater()` invoked within the `call()` function?

This is done because it is not recommended to perform JavaFX UI operations in a separate thread other than the JavaFX Application thread. So to make sure the UI related operations are executed in the JavaFX Application thread we call them inside of the `Platform.runLater()`

**References**

[Task - A Task Which Modifies The Scene Graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

[JavaFX: Interoperability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)